# Compress JSON to GZIP and Upload to S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, compression, gzip

I'm trying to pull in JSON from a lambda, compress it to gzip format and upload to s3. I can do all of this except compress it to gzip. I have pulled various bit of code from here (S.O.) the first code but does not seem to work correctly. Here is what I have tried and the outcome:

this first method seems to make the file much smaller and is gzip format:

```
public void compressAndUpload(AmazonS3 s3, InputStream in) throws IOException {
    Path tmpPath = Files.createTempFile("atest", ".json.gz");
    OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(tmpPath);
    GzipCompressorOutputStream gzOut = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(out);
    IOUtils.copy(in, gzOut);
    InputStream fileIn = Files.newInputStream(tmpPath);
    long size = Files.size(tmpPath);

    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentType("application/x-gzip");
    metadata.setContentLength(size);

    s3.putObject(bucketName, "atest.json.gz", fileIn, metadata);
}
```

However, when I pull it to my local machine, but when I try to use 'gunzip' on it i get the following error message:

```
 gzip: atest.json.gz: unexpected end of file
```

this next method when is not actually compressing the file and when i pull it down locally it says "not in gzip format"

```
public String handleRequest(Input input, Context context) { 
    try {
        byte[] btArr = compress(input.getMessage());
        
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType("application/x-gzip");
        metadata.setContentLength(btArr.length);
        
        AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient().putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, "test22.json.gz",
                new ByteArrayInputStream(btArr), metadata));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static byte[] compress(String str) throws Exception {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println("String length : " + str.length());
    ByteArrayOutputStream obj=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GzipCompressorOutputStream gzip = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(obj);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    gzip.flush(); <-------******Update: This was missing.. caused it to fail.
    gzip.close();
    
    return obj.toByteArray();
 }
```

Am I missing a step here? I feel like this should be a fairly straight forward thing...

Comment: Are you flushing the buffer when you write the `.gz` file?  If the tail of the file is left in the buffer, unwritten, that would give an unexpected EoF message.

Comment: Yes! that was dumb. I added gzip.flush() after the write and it now works as expected. Thanks, rossum!